# Mejorar programa que muestra números primos hasta un valor introducido. Java

Tags: java

Me piden mejorar este código teniendo en cuenta que:

- El único numero primo que es par es el 2.
- Un numero *n* no puede tener divisores mayores que *n*/2.

```
    public static boolean esPrimo(int numero){
        
        boolean esPrimo=true;
        for(int i=2;(i<numero)&&esPrimo;i++){
            if(numero%i==0){
                esPrimo=false;
            }
        }
        return esPrimo;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tec = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero=0;
        System.out.print("Introduce un numero entero: ");
        numero=tec.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=numero;i++){
            if(esPrimo(i)){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        tec.close();
    }
```

¿Por que será más eficiente el programa teniendo en cuenta esas dos cosas? Entiendo que tiene una explicación matemática pero no consigo dar con ella.

Comment: 1) No tienes que recorrer divisores sino sólo validar si es par y es mayor que 2. Te ahorras tiempo. 2) Es más barato validar divisores hasta n/2 y no seguir probando si otros números hacen división entera. Si lo piensas, tiene sentido. Si estás revisando a 33, no hay ningún entero mayor a 16 que puedas probar, que esté entre 1 y 2, y que divida a 33. Y así... siempre piensas en iteraciones que te vas a ahorrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado un número N, el bucle comprueba todos los números desde 2 hasta N-1.

- Sabiendo que los pares mayores que dos no son primos, puedes ahorrarte la mitad de las comprobaciones (compruebas si N es par antes de entrar al bucle y luego compruebas usando

  ```
  for (int i=3, i< numero; i+=2) {...}
  ```
- Sabiendo que el divisor más grande que puede tener un número N (que no sea él mismo) es N/2, puedes de nuevo reducir la búsqueda:

  ```
  int limite = (int)numero / 2;
  for (int i=3, i< limite; i+=2) {...}
  ```

Pero puedes ir más allá: Si un número no es primo, tiene dos divisores<sup>*</sup>, A y B distintos de 1 y de si mismo, porque

```
N / A = B
```

implica que

```
N / B = A
```

Por lo que si encuentras A, no necesitas comprobar B.

El asterisco que he puesto es porque hay dos posibilidades: `A != B` y `A == B`, en cuyo caso sólo tiene un divisor que coincide con el resultado de la división:

O uno es mayor que otro o los dos son el mismo (25 es 5 * 5, mientras que 15 es 3 * 5.

Por tanto encontrás uno antes que otro o encontrás que los dos son el mismo... por lo que en lugar de mirar hasta N/2 puedes mirar "sólo" hasta la raíz cuadrada de ese número. Es decir, si quieres comprobar si 9997 es primo, con mirar hasta 100 sería suficiente.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, lo entendí perfectamente, y agradezco esa siguiente mejora, la tendré en cuenta.